# Sorting Both MySQL Columns and PHP Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I've recently been making a [stats system](http://stats.pm-mc.com/mci/?page=0&order=score) that reads from a database of players and sorts them in various ways. As you can see it works great, but my main problem being is that I need to sort the "Games Played" and "K/D Ratio" columns. But these columns are not stored in the MySQL database, the "Games Played" column is calculated by adding the "Wins" and "Losses" column. Likewise, the "K/D Ratio" column is calculated by dividing "Kills" by "Deaths".

I am using this to sort stats:

`SELECT * FROM stats ORDER BY <filter> DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET <index>`

However, I also need to sort the two columns mentioned above. What would be the best way to go about this? I'm trying to avoid moving it to an array, but if it is unavoidable, I suppose I'll have to.

Comment: You definitely want to try to do the sorting in the database, as this will be exponentially faster than sorting in the JavaScript engine.

Comment: The database engine was designed for, among other things, sorting data.

Comment: You're forcing the client to do it rather than the server to do it, which is bad practice. Also, either way it would need to query the server for each sort, which is redundant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, (Wins + Losses) AS GamesPlayed, (Kills / IFNULL(Deaths, Kills)) AS KDRatio FROM stats ORDER BY GamesPlayed DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET <index>
```

You don't even needed to calculate the total games played in PHP, MySQL can be done for you and also usable for sorting.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *,(kills_column/deaths_column) AS kdratio FROM stats ORDER BY kdratio DESC
```

Comment: You absolutely need to check for division by zero in your query.